# ubuntu doesn't seem to be picking up .bash_profile

Tags: ubuntu, environment-variables

I added some settings to .bash_profile and closing/opening terminal doesn't seem to have the path's I added there i.e. doing `echo $BLAH` results in a empty line.

(running the latest version of ubuntu)

do I use .profile instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to add that in the .profile file in your home directory instead of .bash_profile

Once you do that, you will have to either log in again or do this in your terminal:

```
$> source .profile
```

Answer (score 1):

`~/.bash_profile` is only sourced on login shells.  You may need to alter your `~/.bashrc` to get your configuration sourced on other interactive shells.

See the [bash man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If .profile and .bash_profile coexists under Ubuntu (at least 10.10 which I am using), .profile will be used, and all the settings in .bash_profile are abandoned.